# how to get transaction details by having the signature?

Tags: transactions, api, cli

I want to know how to get transaction data like [from address] [to address] [amount]
by providing the signature of the transaction.
if it's by curl to get data from [SOLANA main network API](https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com) or SOLANA CLI

Answer (score 1):

This Typescript function should achieve what you want. It will return basic details like you want, assuming `transfer` is the first instruction in the transaction.

```
const getTransferDetails = async (tx: string) => {
  const data = {
    method: 'getTransaction',
    jsonrpc: '2.0',
    id: "1",
    params: [
      tx,
      { encoding: 'jsonParsed', commitment: "finalized" }
    ],
  }

  const response = await fetch("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })


  const json = await response.json()
  if (!json.result) {
    return { receiver: null, sender: null }
  }

  // Notice I'm taking the zero index, because like I mentioned earlier, I'm assuming this transaction transfer instruction being first or the only one
  const instruction = json.result.transaction.message.instructions[0]

  // This will give you an object containing "destination", "source" and "amount"
  const { destination, source, amount } = instruction.parsed.info

  return { receiver: destination, sender: source, amount }
}
```

Ultimately, you would need to filter the returned parsed transaction data, so a CURL request would be a bit more difficult and not readable.